# Swift - code re-use

Tags: swift, uitextfield, uilabel

I’m after some advice on code re-use.

I have a view controller that has (at this stage) 12 x labels and 12 x text fields.

For each of these labels and fields, there are lines of code that are duplicated (see commented lines below).

I was wondering the best approach to re-use the lines of code in the creation of the labels and text fields, without re-writing them all the time.

I’ve looked into extension’s, creating a class and also subclassing the common lines of code, but I keep hitting walls.

I already use a class for padding the text fields and understand how that works, but I can’t seem to add other common attributes into that class. Thanks

example:

```
let LabelA = UILabel()
// LabelA.backgroundColor = .clear
// LabelA.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 150).isActive = true
// LabelA.font = LabelA.font.withSize(18)
// LabelA.textAlignment = .left
LabelA.text = “This is my 1st label of 12“

let LabelB = UILabel()
// LabelB.backgroundColor = .clear
// LabelB.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 150).isActive = true
// LabelB.font = LabelB.font.withSize(18)
// LabelB.textAlignment = .left
LabelB.text = “This is my 2nd label of 12“

let LabelC = UILabel()
// LabelC.backgroundColor = .clear
// LabelC.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 150).isActive = true
// LabelC.font = LabelC.font.withSize(18)
// LabelC.textAlignment = .left
LabelC.text = “This is my 3rd label of 12“
```

** **Update** **

Thanks for all the comments.

I am now re-using common lines of code by adding a func to my padding class.

Unfortunately, the text field padding is no longer working.

```
class PaddedTextField: UITextField {

    let padding = UIEdgeInsets(top: 0, left: 5, bottom: 0, right: 5);

    override func textRect(forBounds bounds: CGRect) -> CGRect {
        return UIEdgeInsetsInsetRect(bounds, padding)
    }

    override func placeholderRect(forBounds bounds: CGRect) -> CGRect {
        return UIEdgeInsetsInsetRect(bounds, padding)
    }

    override func editingRect(forBounds bounds: CGRect) -> CGRect {
        return UIEdgeInsetsInsetRect(bounds, padding)
    }

    func createText(with text: String) -> UITextField {
        let txtField = UITextField()
        txtField.backgroundColor = .clear
        txtField.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 250).isActive = true
        txtField.layer.borderWidth = 1
        txtField.layer.borderColor = UIColor(r: 203, g: 203, b: 203).cgColor
        txtField.layer.cornerRadius = 5
        txtField.layer.masksToBounds = true
        txtField.placeholder = text
        txtField.isEnabled = true
        return txtField
    }
}
```

So, this line of code works without the field padding added...

```
let textFieldA = PaddedTextField().createText(with: "placeholder text...")
```

... and this works with field padding, but not re-using the common lines of code.

```
let textFieldB = PaddedTextField()
textFieldB.backgroundColor = .clear
textFieldB.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 250).isActive = true
textFieldB.layer.borderWidth = 1
textFieldB.layer.borderColor = UIColor(r: 203, g: 203, b: 203).cgColor
textFieldB.layer.cornerRadius = 5
textFieldB.layer.masksToBounds = true
textFieldB.placeholder = "textFieldB placeholder text..."
textFieldB.isEnabled = true
```

I am not sure what parts I have wrong / don't understand.  Thanks.

Comment: "subclassing the common lines of code, but I keep hitting walls". What were the walls?

Comment: @Lawliet the walls I keep hitting are things like adding func's and but not getting the results i expect.  As per my update to the OP.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Creating a UILabel subclass with those repeated properties is probably the most effective and clean approach.

A second approach would be to create a ***factory***

For example:

```
private class func factoryLabel() -> UILabel
{
   let label = UILabel()
   label.backgroundColor = .clear
   label.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 150).isActive = true
   label.font = LabelC.font.withSize(18)
   label.textAlignment = .left

   return label
}
```

...

```
let LabelB = myClass.factoryLabel()
LabelB.text = “This is my 2nd label of 12“
```

The example here is a class func, you need to call it as a static func, i.e. with the name of the class.

---

**Update**

In your update you are not exactly using a factory, you are creating a subclass of `UITextField` and inside that subclass factoring a `UITextField` (i.e. **not** factoring your subclass )

As you already have the subclass having a factory is not really necessary, change your class to this:

```
class PaddedTextField:UITextField
{
    private let padding:UIEdgeInsets = UIEdgeInsets(top: 0, left: 5, bottom: 0, right: 5);

    init(with text:String)
    {
        super.init(frame:CGRect.zero)
        backgroundColor = .clear
        widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant:250).isActive = true
        layer.borderWidth = 1
        layer.borderColor = UIColor(r: 203, g: 203, b: 203).cgColor
        layer.cornerRadius = 5
        layer.masksToBounds = true
        placeholder = text
        isEnabled = true
    }

    required init?(coder aDecoder:NSCoder)
    {
        return nil
    }

    override func textRect(forBounds bounds:CGRect) -> CGRect
    {
        return UIEdgeInsetsInsetRect(bounds, padding)
    }

    override func placeholderRect(forBounds bounds:CGRect) -> CGRect
    {
        return UIEdgeInsetsInsetRect(bounds, padding)
    }

    override func editingRect(forBounds bounds:CGRect) -> CGRect
    {
        return UIEdgeInsetsInsetRect(bounds, padding)
    }
}
```

And now instantiate it like this:

```
let textFieldA = PaddedTextField(with: "placeholder text...")
```

Comment: Thanks, I have implemented part of your answer and I will look more into "factory's".

Comment: @K1llarney Just updated my answer, please take a look at it.

Comment: Thank you zero, you are a champion.

Answer (score 1):

Simple solution is a function passing the text string as a parameter and returning the label:

```
func createLabel(with text: String) -> UILabel
{
   let label = UILabel()
   label.backgroundColor = .clear
   label.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 150).isActive = true
   label.font = LabelC.font.withSize(18)
   label.textAlignment = .left
   label.text = text
   return label
}

let labelA = createLabel(with: "This is my 1st label of 12")
let labelB = createLabel(with: "This is my 2nd label of 12")
let labelC = createLabel(with: "This is my 3rd label of 12")
```

** **Update** **

In case of subclassing `UITextField` I recommend to overwrite the two designated `init` methods and add a common method for the additional setup and a class method to set the text property. The benefit is that the additional setup is also considered if the text field is created in Interface Builder with `init(coder`

```
class PaddedTextField: UITextField {

    class func create(with text: String) -> PaddedTextField
    {
        let field = PaddedTextField()
        field.text = text
        return field
    }

    let padding = UIEdgeInsets(top: 0, left: 5, bottom: 0, right: 5);

    override func textRect(forBounds bounds: CGRect) -> CGRect {
        return UIEdgeInsetsInsetRect(bounds, padding)
    }

    override func placeholderRect(forBounds bounds: CGRect) -> CGRect {
        return UIEdgeInsetsInsetRect(bounds, padding)
    }

    override func editingRect(forBounds bounds: CGRect) -> CGRect {
        return UIEdgeInsetsInsetRect(bounds, padding)
    }

    override init(frame: CGRect) {
        super.init(frame: frame)
        setup()
    }

    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(coder: aDecoder)
        setup()
    }

    func setup() {
        self.backgroundColor = .clear
        self.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 250).isActive = true
        self.layer.borderWidth = 1
        self.layer.borderColor = UIColor(white: 0.796, alpha: 1.0).cgColor
        self.layer.cornerRadius = 5
        self.layer.masksToBounds = true
        self.placeholder = text
        self.isEnabled = true
    }
}


let labelA = PaddedTextField.create(with: "This is my 1st label of 12")
let labelB = PaddedTextField.create(with: "This is my 2nd label of 12")
let labelC = PaddedTextField.create(with: "This is my 3rd label of 12")
```

Comment: Thanks, I have implemented your answer, but still have a problem as mentioned in my OP update.

Answer (score 0):

In this case I would use stackview (here is a great [talk](https://talk.objc.io/episodes/S01E51-playground-driven-development-at-kickstarter) on that), so you don't have to be bothered by paddings, etc, all the time.

You can create a function like this:

```
func mkInput(with text: String) -> (UILabel, UITextField) {
    let label: UILabel
    let textField: UITextField
    // config these as you want...
    return (label, textField)
}
```

Than you can create a collection from strings like:

```
let inputs: [(UILabel, UITextField)] = labelStrings.map { mkInput(with: $0) }
```

And so on. :)

Comment: Thanks for your input Adam.  FYI...  I am using a stack view after I set the labels and also after I set the text fields.  I am using the padding because the fields are being created programatically with a border and they need that padding at the front.